# Make UIButton Click Display UIWebview

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview, uibutton

I'm trying to load a specific URL after clicking a button. I have the webView code inside of a `UIButton` action, but I'm not sure how to pull that into the display/viewDidLoad method it will work. But I need to be able to change the URL with different buttons.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var radioURL = "http://www.ladiescanwetalk.org/category/podcasts/"

    @IBOutlet weak var mainWebView: UIWebView!

    @IBAction func loadRadioView(sender: UIButton) {
        let getCurrentURL = NSURL (string: radioURL)
        let requestCurrentURL = NSURLRequest(URL: getCurrentURL!)
        self.mainWebView?.loadRequest(requestCurrentURL)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best to achieve what you're asking is to set a different `tag` value for each value (you can do this either using Storyboard or directly via code).

Your code will be something like this:

```
@IBAction func loadRadioView(sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.tag == 1 {
        radioURL = "http://anotherUrl"
    } else if sender.tag == 2 {
        radioURL = "http://yetanotherurl"
    } else if sender.tag == 3 {
        radioURL = "http://....."
    }

    let getCurrentURL = NSURL (string: radioURL)
    let requestCurrentURL = NSURLRequest(URL: getCurrentURL!)
    self.mainWebView?.loadRequest(requestCurrentURL)

}
```

Comment: I disagree – I think tags make this indirect. If you have different buttons, declare properties for each and check if the sender is equal to each button. There's no need to try to figure out which tag relates to which buttons when you can have descriptive property names.